# Django admin raw_id_fields and auto-populating other fields

Tags: django, django-admin

Suppose I have the following in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Sales(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()

class SalesItem(models.Model):
    sales = models.ForeignKey(Sales)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I use django admin with the following in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Product, Sales, SalesItem

class SalesItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SalesItem
    raw_id_fields = ('product',)

class SalesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (SalesItemInline,)

admin.site.register(Product)
admin.site.register(Sales, SalesAdmin)
```

In order to fill new sales item form, user clicks the magnifying glass icon, choose the product, then product field of the sales item will be filled with the product ID. Along with that, I would like to have the price field auto-populated with the chosen product.price value.

What is the most idiomatic django way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you what to show the price field to user? Otherwise, you can do it in forms view.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The context is new Sales screen. Because SalesAdmin has inline, new Sales screen will show blank SalesItem (3 by default) which user has to fill, each with product, quantity, and price. Because I use raw_id_fields, the product field will have magnifying glass icon. Upon selection, only this field is filled with the ID. I want the price field filled too, with the price of the chosen product.